# Is there a movement penalty when starting in the same room as an opponent?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In Betrayal at House on the Hill there is a rule for **Moving Past Opponents** on page 17:

> For **each** opponent in a room with it after the haunt starts, an
>   explorer or monster must use 1 extra space of movement to leave that
>   room. (Heroes slow down the traitor and monsters, and vice versa.)
>
> No matter how many penalties you have on a turn, you can always move
>   at least 1 space. This is also true if a monster rolls a 0 for
>   movement (see "How Monsters Work," page 18).
>
> Stunned monsters don't slow an explorer's movement in this way.

I interpret "moving past an opponent" as walking into a room with an opponent, then walking out. Is there a movement penalty if you are ALREADY in the room with your opponent at the beginning of a turn?

For example, say I am in a room with 3 zombies at the start of the turn. Does it take me 4 movement points to leave the room (1 for each zombie and 1 as a normal movement point) OR does it take me 1 movement point?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I interpret "moving past an opponent" as walking into a room with an opponent

It doesn't say "to move past an opponent", it says "to leave that room."

> Is there a movement penalty if you are ALREADY in the room with your opponent at the beginning of a turn?

Yes, there's a movement penalty for leaving a room with an opponent. This penalty is not conditional on you having started in another room.

> For example, say I am in a room with 3 zombies at the start of the turn. Does it take me 4 movement points to leave the room (1 for each zombie and 1 as a normal movement point) OR does it take me 1 movement point?

It will take 4 points if you have at least that many. If you have less, it will take however many you have (including none) since you can always move at least once.

Comment: "Moving Past Opponents" is the section title. If the title had simply been "Leaving Rooms Containing Opponents" then I feel the rules would be clearer and there would be no room for discussion. As a first time player the penalty for leaving rooms penalty seems very unbalanced as almost all heroes only have a 3 or 4 base movement speed. A single monster in a room with a hero effectively means that it is very difficult to escape. Multiple monsters in a room with a hero make it nearly impossible to escape. I've only played one scenario though... perhaps the penalty is more balanced in others.

Comment: @Jon the idea is that you are moving past them within the room, to get to the door.

Comment: The title is conceptual, and it should be hard to escape when you're surrounded!

Comment: @Sparr If we go with that thought then we should track which door players/monsters enter. If I enter a room via door A and monsters enter via door B then I should at least be able to retreat through door A without penalty.

Comment: You could always make that a house rule.

Comment: @ikegami But I am very spry and zombies are slow. I was dodging and weaving during the fights such that I was positioned right next to the door I wanted to use. I've watched many seasons of Walking Dead! :)

Comment: @Jon I disagree. There is no reason you would assume a monster would be/stay near door B. They are just "in the room". Your turn is not instantaneous, you are "in the room" with them for some seconds of game time (long enough to ascertain that they are there, at least) in-character, so you have to deal with them (evasion or otherwise) regardless of what other actions you take.